# Custom forms with HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

Will there be any issues with creating a custom form in the index page?  Will I be able to get and post requests?  It's a simple email validation form and once validated, the user will be able to download a file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In theory, this should work just fine if you are putting the code directly into a theme file, and not into a post body or something. However, it is very dependent on your site's setup. Here are some things to watch out for:

- *Permalink structure:* if using GET requests to process the form, test to make sure they aren't getting overwritten or trashed by the .htaccess rules.
- *Reserved words:* be careful not to use some variable names/terms that WordPress uses internally. See [the Codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) for a mostly complete list, and [this forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/reserved-wordsparams-list) that gives some experiences with it. The best way to resolve it? Preface all of your form elements with a custom prefix, like `my_email_validation_xxxxx` where xxxxx is the field you want.
- *Processing page:* you may need to be creative on where the processing occurs to handle the form. It will be easiest to send this to a standalone PHP file not associated with WordPress to do the validation, and have that redirect to a normal WordPress page to continue the process.